# Thank you, C. Lange and Alec

Tags: discussion, moderators

As some may have noticed, Alec and C. Lange have stepped away from moderating on the site, although they still intend to remain at least somewhat active as participants. It's been a pleasure working with them for the past couple of years, and I wish you both the best in your journey forward!

Thank you both for your service and dedication to promoting and keeping the site going during your tenure, and I wish you the best.

The community managers have been in touch, and I expect we will be having an election soon.