# Announcing a “Graduation” election for 2023

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

**Summary**: Physical Fitness Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [an election](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/election/2) on **August 22, 2023**, as your “graduation” election. This is going to be [a second attempt at a graduation election](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/a/862/15307), brought about by [the recent departure of two members of the moderator team](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/q/911/15307), leaving the team with a single moderator.

The timeline:

- On August 15, I'll post a question collection post on Meta, so that the community can post questions they'd like to see the candidates answer.
- Starting on August 22, users can [nominate themselves](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/election/2). The top questions collected on the previous week will be compiled into a questionnaire on the election page, so that potential moderators can answer them.
- The existing moderator team will need to run in the election if they wish to keep their positions.
- On August 29, if there are 4 or more candidates, the election will move into the voting phase. If not, we'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period, there are still fewer than 4 candidates, we'll simply appoint the candidates who've nominated (and aren't already pro-tem mods), and we'll default to considering this a "pro-tem election" just to try to bring the total number of moderators on the site up to 3 (for full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections)). (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year).)
- If the election moves into the voting phase, we'll announce the results on Meta on September 6 (or September 13, if we need to extend the nomination period).

If you have any questions about the process, please post them in an answer here.